# Pivot the result of SPLIT_STRING?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a column with strings like these:

```
/TYPE/BOOKING/IBAN/NL12BANK0003456789/BIC/BANKNL2A/NAME/Mr. A. Someguy/CODE/Codenumber 12345678/REF/NOTPROVIDED/LINE/ABCD EFG 234567890 1234 ETC
/TYPE/BOOKING/IBAN/NL34BANK000123456/BIC/BANKNL2U/NAME/Mr. A. Dinges/CODE/98765432/REF/NOTPROVIDED
```

And I want to look up individual elements in these strings without having to write unreadable code with many CHARINDEX-es and SUBSTRINGS. So I found the SPLIT_STRING function.

```
select contract, [value]
from SCHEMA.PAYMENTS
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(paymentrow, '/')
```

It's great, but now I get these values in rows:

```
bookingnumber   value
12-3-56789012-3 
12-3-56789012-3 TYPE
12-3-56789012-3 BOOKING
12-3-56789012-3 IBAN
12-3-56789012-3 NL12BANK0003456789
12-3-56789012-3 BIC
12-3-56789012-3 BANKNL2A
12-3-56789012-3 NAME
12-3-56789012-3 Mr. A. Someguy
12-3-56789012-3 CODE
12-3-56789012-3 Codenumber 12345678
12-3-56789012-3 REF
12-3-56789012-3 NOTPROVIDED
12-3-56789012-3 LINE
12-3-56789012-3 ABCD EFG 234567890 1234 ETC
98-7-65431234-0 
98-7-65431234-0 TYPE
98-7-65431234-0 BOOKING
98-7-65431234-0 IBAN
98-7-65431234-0 NL34BANK000123456
98-7-65431234-0 BIC
98-7-65431234-0 BANKNL2U
98-7-65431234-0 NAME
98-7-65431234-0 Mr. A. Dinges
98-7-65431234-0 CODE
98-7-65431234-0 98765432
98-7-65431234-0 REF
98-7-65431234-0 NOTPROVIDED
```

So as a final step, I would to pivot the value column so that the elements in the original string appear as neat columns, like this:

```
bookingnumber    type     IBAN                BIC       name            code                 ref
12-3-56789012-3  BOOKING  NL12BANK0003456789  BANKNL2A  Mr. A. Someguy  Codenumber 12345678  NOTPROVIDED
98-7-65431234-0  BOOKING  NL34BANK0001234567  BANKNL2U  Mr. A. Dinges   98765432             NOTPROVIDED
```

I've been tinkering with PIVOT, but either it doesn't work, or it doesn't give the right results.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you always have the same columns or are the columns dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own attempt calling `STRING_SPLIT()` proofs, that you are using v2016+. So you can call JSON to your rescue:

(Credits to John Cappelletti for the *mockup*)

```
Declare @YourTable table (Bookingnumber varchar(50),paymentrow varchar(max) )
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('12-3-56789012-3','/TYPE/BOOKING/IBAN/NL12BANK0003456789/BIC/BANKNL2A/NAME/Mr. A. Someguy/CODE/Codenumber 12345678/REF/NOTPROVIDED/LINE/ABCD EFG 234567890 1234 ETC')
,('98-7-65431234-0','/TYPE/BOOKING/IBAN/NL34BANK000123456/BIC/BANKNL2U/NAME/Mr. A. Dinges/CODE/98765432/REF/NOTPROVIDED');

SELECT *
FROM @YourTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('[{',REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                                        t.paymentrow,'/TYPE/','"Type":"')
                                                     ,'/IBAN/','","IBAN":"')
                                                     ,'/BIC/','","BIC":"')
                                                     ,'/NAME/','","Name":"')
                                                     ,'/CODE/','","Code":"')
                                                     ,'/REF/','","Ref":"')
                                                     ,'/LINE/','","Line":"'),'"}]'))
            WITH([Type] NVARCHAR(100)
                ,[IBAN] NVARCHAR(100)
                ,[BIC] NVARCHAR(100)
                ,[Name] NVARCHAR(250)
                ,[Code] NVARCHAR(100)
                ,[Ref] NVARCHAR(100)
                ,[Line] NVARCHAR(500)) A;
```

We use some replacements to transform your string to such a JSON

```
[{"Type":"BOOKING",
  "IBAN":"NL12BANK0003456789",
  "BIC":"BANKNL2A",
  "Name":"Mr. A. Someguy",
  "Code":"Codenumber 12345678",
  "Ref":"NOTPROVIDED",
  "Line":"ABCD EFG 234567890 1234 ETC"}]
```

The `WITH`-clause will do the pivoting implicitly.

### UPDATE If this is position-safe

With a fixed input pattern, this is easier

```
SELECT *
FROM @YourTable t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CONCAT('[["',REPLACE(STUFF(t.paymentrow,1,1,''),'/','","'),'"]]'))
            WITH([Type] NVARCHAR(100) '$[1]'
                ,[IBAN] NVARCHAR(100) '$[3]'
                ,[BIC] NVARCHAR(100) '$[5]'
                ,[Name] NVARCHAR(250) '$[7]'
                ,[Code] NVARCHAR(100) '$[9]'
                ,[Ref] NVARCHAR(100) '$[11]'
                ,[Line] NVARCHAR(500) '$[13]') A;
```

The intermediate JSON-array looks like this:

```
["TYPE","BOOKING","IBAN","NL12BANK0003456789","BIC","BANKNL2A","NAME","Mr. A. Someguy","CODE","Codenumber 12345678","REF","NOTPROVIDED","LINE","ABCD EFG 234567890 1234 ETC"]
```

Comment: Toyed with the idea of JSON.  I like this better because there is no worries about sequence

Comment: @JohnCappelletti As commented below your answer, the splitting and fetching with a fix position (`/x[3]`) will respect the sort order too. A similar approach is possible with JSON too, just added an update to my answer.

Comment: Actually I like the first one very much, because I can actually address the new column names. This works well for me.

Comment: @Marcel-JanKrijgsman Yeah, Json is a great help with string manipulations. And its parsing engine is lightning fast.

Answer (score 3):

IF the columns are not dynamic, perhaps a little XML

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Bookingnumber varchar(50),paymentrow varchar(max) )
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('12-3-56789012-3','/TYPE/BOOKING/IBAN/NL12BANK0003456789/BIC/BANKNL2A/NAME/Mr. A. Someguy/CODE/Codenumber 12345678/REF/NOTPROVIDED/LINE/ABCD EFG 234567890 1234 ETC')
,('98-7-65431234-0','/TYPE/BOOKING/IBAN/NL34BANK000123456/BIC/BANKNL2U/NAME/Mr. A. Dinges/CODE/98765432/REF/NOTPROVIDED')

Select A.Bookingnumber
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Type = xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                      ,IBan = xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')
                      ,BIC  = xDim.value('/x[7]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Name = xDim.value('/x[9]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Code = xDim.value('/x[11]','varchar(max)')
                      ,Ref  = xDim.value('/x[13]','varchar(max)')
                From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace(paymentrow,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) as A(xDim)
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: when using `For XML Path('')` like this is this 100% guaranteed having a deterministic order always, the manual does not mention it..  For some reason it does not feel totally "safe"

Comment: @RaymondNijland Never seen it in writing, but I have NEVER EVER EVER seen it fail.  We've had exhaustive debates, discussion, and testing.   I have even tried to break it.   Now, I can't GTD that the sun will rise tomorrow morning, but I will wager it will.  :)

Comment: *"Never seen it in writing, but I have NEVER EVER EVER seen it fail. We've had exhaustive debates, discussion, and testing. I have even tried to break it"* fair enough just started to learn SQL Server meself so just checking you know :-) ..

Comment: .. well somewhere after what rethinking it does make sense you could not break it  `FOR XML PATH` suggest SQL Server is starting internally a XML parser with xpath support, the parsing stream can not really change it's order how it parses XML nodes..

Comment: @RaymondNijland This approach is save to use. The element order is an implicit part of the XML (As a side note: Be aware, that is NOT true for attributes.) Fetching the values by their position (like `[/x[7]]`) will work. But you must rely on the same pattern and no missing parts in your input. I just added a JSON approach, just as an alternative, but +1 from my side, great answer!

Comment: *"This approach is save to use. The element order is an implicit part of the XML (As a side note: Be aware, that is NOT true for attributes.) Fetching the values by their position (like [/x[7]]) will work."* @Shnugo yes that would make sense that it would fail with attributes or with missing XML nodes. when xpath selecting Thanks for the extra be aware note..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Might be, that I was not completely clear: The sort order of XML nodes is fix, but the sort order of XML attributes is not. The problem with string-splitting is, that any approach returning a **result set** is handled by the engine as any other set. So, after splitting, you'd need a reliable `ORDER BY` to guarantee the sort order. `STRING_SPLIT()` does not carry this index. But the JSON-splitting via JSON-array is position safe. That means: Before v2016 the XML splitter is a good workaround. With v2016 I'd prefer a JSON splitter (and hope for a repair on `STRING_SPLIT()`...)

Comment: @Shnugo , i catched on what you meant before you wrote your last comment i am pretty sure i describe it very bad it is still friday evening ... *"The element order is an implicit part of the XML (As a side note: Be aware, that is NOT true for attributes.)"* True assuming XMLSchema (XSD) where XML elements can have a defined fixed position (`sequence`) where attributes can't be defined like that anyhow also pretty sure something like this is also defined in the XML specs aswell that sort of attributes in xml nodes is "meaningless".

Comment: Thanks @JohnCappelleti for the quick response and effort. I'm going with the JSON approach, because I had some problems getting the right items from the real table. By using the named items with OPENJSON I could not make that mistake.

Comment: @Marcel-JanKrijgsman No worries.  :)  I follow Shnugo closely ... if not stalk.  That makes SO fabulous, you get options.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  contract
,       x.value('/M[3]', 'nvarchar(max)') as IBAN
,       x.value('/M[5]', 'nvarchar(max)') as BIC
,       x.value('/M[7]', 'nvarchar(max)') as NAME
FROM    (
        SELECT  contract
        ,       CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(paymentrow, '/', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS xml) AS x
        FROM    payments
        ) sub
```

[Example at dbfiddle.co.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7c2a51720789dfc8fa04e2944fc44d37)

Comment: I took the time to try your solution as well. It works too. Thanks for the effort!